# Python checking timestamps with if statements not working correctly

Tags: python, if-statement

I have these `if` statements that should be checking timestamps. The last `if` statement doesn't seem to work. These timestamp values should show retrieved timestamp is greater than current - two months, but that doesn't happen. When ran with the following values the last `if` statement gets triggered.

as requested:
    order date 2018-12-17T16:58:00-06:00
  values:

```
one month 2592000
two months 5184000
current timestamp 1545247709.1553745
retrieved timestamp 1545026400
current - two months 1540063709.1553745


one month 259200 <class 'int'>
two months 5184000 <class 'int'>
current timestamp 1545252986.085405 <class 'float'>
retrieved timestamp 1545026400 <class 'int'>



   if order_count > 1:
    for result in results['orders']:
        order_status_info= self_api.which_api('order_statuses/%d' % result['order_status_id'])
        for customer_blocked_reason in customer_blocked_reasons:
            if customer_blocked_reason in order_status_info['name']:
                customer_is_blocked = True


   order_id                 = 0
        order_date          = result['ordered_at']
        two_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 60
        one_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 30
        stripped_date       = order_date[:order_date.find("T")]
        current_timestamp   = time.time()
        retrieved_timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(stripped_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%s"))
        print("one month", one_month_seconds)
        print("two months", two_month_seconds)
        print("current timestamp", current_timestamp)
        print("retrieved timestamp", retrieved_timestamp)
        print("current - two months", current_timestamp - two_month_seconds)

        if retrieved_timestamp > (current_timestamp - one_month_seconds) and not customer_is_blocked:
            status['success'] = 1
            status['message'] = "Customer Verified with orders older than 30 days and no blocking reasons"
            break

        elif customer_is_blocked:
            status_change_result = self_order.update_status(order_statuses['order_hold_manager_review'])
            status['success']    = 1
            status['message']    = "Changed order status to Order Hold - Manager Review"
            break

        elif retrieved_timestamp < (current_timestamp - two_month_seconds):
            status['success'] = 0
            status['message'] = "There is more than 1 order, and none are greater than 60 days, we need to check manually"
```

Comment: Have you checked your data types? What does current_timestamp - one_month_seconds return as a data type?

Comment: just tried that heres the result : current - one month 1542658409.0589633              I had tried turning current into a int but that didnt change anything.

Comment: No, not that value, the data type.

Comment: ok its returning floats however i just tried turning current_timestamp to an integer so now its returning integers and still no different

Comment: Please put in valid Python for the values. It looks to me like you are comparing a string to an int...

Comment: what is the value of `order_date` ??

Comment: The first `if` gets executed if the retrieving date is **within the last 30 days** (and the user isnt blocked, of course) but that doesn't seem to be your intention because of the message you are creating: **"Customer Verified with orders older than 30 days and no blocking reasons"**

Answer (score 0):

The 'break' statements shouldn't be outside of a loop.  But normally the interpreter would catch this. So there must be more code involved, maybe the problem is there.  I copied the logic here and assigned the given values to the variables and I get the first option if customer_is_blocked == False and the second option if it is False

```
two_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 60
one_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 30
current_timestamp   = 1545247709.1553745
retrieved_timestamp = 1545026400
customer_is_blocked = True

if retrieved_timestamp > (current_timestamp - one_month_seconds) and not customer_is_blocked:
    print(1)
elif customer_is_blocked:
    print(2)
elif retrieved_timestamp < (current_timestamp - two_month_seconds):
    print(3)
```

Did you assign 'False' or 'false' (string) to customer_is_blocked instead of False?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and, after assigning manually to each variable, this seems to be working. I didn't changed anything except replace `strftime("%s")` with `timestamp()` because I was getting an error: `ValueError: Invalid format string`.

```python
import datetime
import time

order_id            = 0

# Manually assign this
order_date          = "2018-12-17T16:58:00-06:00"
customer_is_blocked = False

two_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 60
one_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 30
stripped_date       = order_date[:order_date.find("T")]
current_timestamp   = time.time()

# This is the only change I did: strftime("%s") => timestamp()
retrieved_timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(stripped_date, "%Y-%m-%d").timestamp())

print("one month", one_month_seconds)
print("two months", two_month_seconds)
print("current timestamp", current_timestamp)
print("retrieved timestamp", retrieved_timestamp)
print("current - two months", current_timestamp - two_month_seconds)

if retrieved_timestamp > (current_timestamp - one_month_seconds) and not customer_is_blocked:
    print(1)
elif customer_is_blocked:
    print(2)
elif retrieved_timestamp < (current_timestamp - two_month_seconds):
    print(3)
```

With the value for `order_date` you provided, the code above prints `1` if `customer_is_blocked == False`, and `2` if `customer_is_blocked == True`.

Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: well i just tried that and added print 1,2 ,3 to the if statements. When I run the code with the values i provided it prints 1. but that order isnt older than 30 days so it shouldnt print one. Maybe im confusing the logic. we are looking if there are orders older than 30 days and 60 days respectively. with order_date set as it is that doesnt meet the first requirement

Comment: So, in the code I posted, do you want that if the order is **older than 30 days and the customer is not blocked** should be **printed 1**??? But, if it is **older than 60 days**, should be **printed 3**???

Comment: @Anon_guy please, if my answer worked for you, mark it as accepted (green checkmar), otherwise let me know what is going on.